# Can this SPARQL query be simplified?

Tags: sparql, rdf, graph-databases

Currently I'm implementing SPARQL queries for [LDBC Benchmark](http://ldbc.github.io/ldbc_snb_docs/ldbc-snb-specification.pdf). I came up with a solution to [bi-read-3](https://ldbc.github.io/ldbc_snb_docs_snapshot/bi-read-03.pdf) query. The relevant part of data schema is the following:
[image]

The query description:

> Find the Tags that were used in Messages during the given month of the given year and the Tags that were used during the next month. For both months, compute the count of Messages that used each of the Tags.

My solution ([with some syntax highlight](https://github.com/antaljanosbenjamin/ldbc_snb_implementations/blob/e21bbe86037ed2fc7e17bd4f81ae357fb4b7a1bb/sparql/bi-3.sparql)):

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX sn: <http://www.ldbc.eu/ldbc_socialnet/1.0/data/>
PREFIX snvoc: <http://www.ldbc.eu/ldbc_socialnet/1.0/vocabulary/>
PREFIX sntag: <http://www.ldbc.eu/ldbc_socialnet/1.0/tag/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>


SELECT ?tagName (SUM(?countMonth1) as ?countMonth1) (SUM(?countMonth2) as ?countMonth2) (ABS( SUM(?countMonth1) - SUM(?countMonth2) ) as ?diff)
WHERE
{ 
  {
    SELECT ?tagName (COUNT(?message) as ?innerCountMonth1)
    WHERE {

      BIND ( 2010 as ?year1 ) .
      BIND ( 9 as ?month1 ) .

      {
        ?message rdf:type snvoc:Comment 
      } UNION {
        ?message rdf:type snvoc:Post 
      } .
      ?message snvoc:creationDate ?creationDate .
      FILTER ((year(?creationDate) = ?year1 && month(?creationDate) = ?month1) )

      ?message snvoc:hasTag ?tag .
      ?tag foaf:name ?tagName .

    }
    GROUP BY ?tagName
  } UNION {
    SELECT ?tagName (COUNT(?message) as ?innerCountMonth2)
    WHERE {

      BIND ( 2010 as ?year1 ) .
      BIND ( 9 as ?month1 ) .
      BIND ( ?year1 + FLOOR(?month1 / 12.0) as ?year2 ) .
      BIND ( IF (?month1 = 12, 1, ?month1 + 1) as ?month2 ) .
      {
        ?message rdf:type snvoc:Comment 
      } UNION {
        ?message rdf:type snvoc:Post 
      } .
      ?message snvoc:creationDate ?creationDate .
      FILTER (year(?creationDate) = ?year2 && month(?creationDate) = ?month2 ) 

      ?message snvoc:hasTag ?tag .
      ?tag foaf:name ?tagName .

    }
    GROUP BY  ?tagName
  }

  BIND ( COALESCE(?innerCountMonth1, 0) as ?countMonth1 )
  BIND ( COALESCE(?innerCountMonth2, 0) as ?countMonth2 )
}
GROUP BY ?tagName
ORDER BY DESC(?diff) ?tagName
```

I have a feeling that there is a simpler solution, but I can't figure it out.

My question is that: This query can be implemented in a simpler/more effective way? E.g.: without nested queries or just a faster way.

I'm really new in SPARQL, so I will appreciate every useful comment or improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX snvoc: <http://www.ldbc.eu/ldbc_socialnet/1.0/vocabulary/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT
?tagName
(SUM(xsd:integer(?isFirst)) AS ?countMonth1)
(SUM(xsd:integer(?isSecond)) AS ?countMonth2)
(ABS(?countMonth1 - ?countMonth2) AS ?diff) 
WHERE
  {
  VALUES (?year1 ?month1) {(2010 9)}
  VALUES (?type) {(snvoc:Comment) (snvoc:Post)}
  ?message a ?type; snvoc:hasTag/foaf:name ?tagName; snvoc:creationDate ?creationDate .
  BIND (year(?creationDate) AS ?year) .
  BIND (month(?creationDate) AS ?month) .
  BIND (IF (?month1 = 12, ?year1 + 1, ?year1     ) AS ?year2) .
  BIND (IF (?month1 = 12,          1, ?month1 + 1) AS ?month2) .
  BIND (((?month1 = ?month) && (?year1 = ?year)) AS ?isFirst) .
  BIND (((?month2 = ?month) && (?year2 = ?year)) AS ?isSecond) .
  FILTER (?isFirst || ?isSecond)
  }
  GROUP BY ?tagName HAVING (bound(?tagName))
```

**Updates**

See comments.

Comment: Thanks! I had to make minor changes, eg: `(ABS(?countMonth1 - ?countMonth2) as ?diff)` instead of `(ABS(SUM(?countMonth1) - SUM(?countMonth2) ) as ?diff)`, `xsd:integer` instead of  `xsd:int` and replace `?name` with `?tagName`, but is works perfectly. [Here](https://github.com/antaljanosbenjamin/ldbc_snb_implementations/blob/sparql-queires/sparql/queries/bi-3.sparql) is the final version. I think it`s not important by now, but you can find test data [here](https://github.com/antaljanosbenjamin/ldbc_snb_implementations/tree/sparql-queires/sparql/test-data)

Comment: @JánosBenjaminAntal OK, thank you very much! I've edited my answer. Also, I've tested the query on a small dataset, the query looks OK (if different tags have different names). BTW, although you do not need nested selects in this particular case, Blazegraph supports the so-called [named subqueries](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/NamedSubquery).

Comment: Thanks for the note! In the future, we will probably use Blazegraph (currently I'm using Stardog), but I think the queries should use features only from the official W3C SPARQL standard. Unfortunately, I didn't find named subquery feature in the standard.